# How to pipe Scilab on Windows

Tags: scilab

I am trying to do simple piping with Scilab on Windows but it doesn't work neither in `cmd.exe` nor in PowerShell.
I know I can pass commands to the interpreter as simple as `echo %pi | scilex -nb -quit`, but I want to pass and read data instead of not directly sending commands.

I am using `mgetl` with file descritor `%io(1)` to access standard input, but the returned value is an empty matrix:

```
>echo Hello, World! | scilex -nb -quit -e "mgetl(%io(1))"
 ans  =

    []
```

If I use `type` and a file, the same behavior happens. Here `tmp` has a line break, but that is irrelevant because the behavior is the same with or without it:

```
>type tmp
Hello, 
World!

>type tmp | scilex -nb -quit -e "mgetl(%io(1))"
 ans  =

    []
```

However, by removing the left-hand side of the pipe and keeping `%io(1)` makes Scilab wait for user input until <kbd>return</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed:

```
>scilex -nb -quit -e "mgetl(%io(1))"
Hello, World!
 ans  =

  "Hello, World!"
```

Using `fd=mopen('tmp'); mgetl(fd), mclose(fd);` as the expression argument works, as expected, but that's not what I want, because it depends on a saved file.
I want to read data directly from the output of another process by using `|` in `cmd.exe` or PowerShell.
What is wrong with this approach? Is this an unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you cannot read stdin with `mgetl`, but with `read` which uses Fortran formats, it works

```
C:\>echo Hello, World! | scilex -nb -e "read(%io(1),1,1,'(a)')"
 ans  =

  "Hello, World! "


C:\>
```

The fact that mgetl cannot read from stdin is a bug that will be fixed in the upcoming release of Scilab (6.1.1) : http://codereview.scilab.org/#/c/21778, thanks for reporting.

Comment: I know I can pass commands, but as I said and the end of the question, I want to read data, not commands and `mgetl` with `%io(1)` is not working. I clarified my question by stressing out about _data_ at the beginning too.

Comment: And why I "cannot read stdin like this"? Is this by design? A decision that the developing team made or is it consequence of something else? If it shouldn't work, then why is Scilab waiting for input in the third exemple tentative I wrote?

Comment: This is by design and works the same on all platforms (Windows, Linux, macOS). About your third example, the Windows version seems to behave differently from LInux/macOS, I get `portmottelet-hz-2:~ mottelet$ scilab -nwni  -nb -quit -e "mgetl(%io(1))"
 ans  =

    []`

Comment: I updated the answer, use read instead of mgetl.

Comment: The fact that mgetl cannot read from stdin is a bug that will be fixed in the upcoming release of Scilab (6.1.1) : https://codereview.scilab.org/#/c/21778/2, thanks for reporting.

Comment: Thank you. Would you consider adding your last comment to the actual answer?